# why I can not filter probably on doc_ents?

Tags: python, entity-framework, nlp, spacy

I am struggling with a very strange things in spacy.
I want to. determine all entity except some of them. So I did this:

```
for ent in x3.ents:
  #  print(str(spacy.explain(ent.label_)))
     if not ent.label_ in [ 'ORG', 'PERSON']:
        if not ent.text in { 'technician', 'service',' hcc'}:
            print(ent.text)
```

but `technician` is printed.

my doc has many rows for example:

```
agricultural English
balancer
front office director
clinical laboratory technician ii
```

for this 4 rows my ent.text is:

```
English
technician
```

Comment: ent.text is a word or a sentence?

Comment: @lgnacio it's actually word.

Comment: Can you add in the question one example of `ent.text`.

Comment: it is done, I edited

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `spacy`, but in the way you are trying to filter the sentence. You will need to compare each word in `ent.text` with the list of words you want to discard (`{ 'technician', 'service',' hcc'}`). For example:

```
# This could be your ent.text
s = "my sentence contains technician"
       
new_s = []
for w in s.split(" "):
    if w not in { 'technician', 'service',' hcc'}:
        new_s.append(w)
# Here you would consider to replace the original ent.text
print(" ".join(new_s))
```

Comment: ok I will, I get this error: `'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no attribute 'split'`

Comment: ok, the root problem is kind of the same, just you will need to convert the types. So what you have in `ent.text` is kind of a collection of words, and you are trying to compare that collection with another set of words. Can you convert `ent.text` into a set? like `set(ent.text)`

Comment: I tried this `[ent for ent in x3.ents if not ent.label_ in ['ORG', 'PERSON'] and not ent in ['nigth','lol']]` but I get error

Comment: @elham I dont have much experience in spacy, but if the following two things are possible I have a solution in mind. Is it possible to convert the content of ent.text into a set() and then from set back to the type of ent.text to reassign?